# Vuetify makes labels too close to controls

Tags: javascript, vue.js, material-design, vuetify.js

I added `Vuetify` plugin to my Vue application like that:

```
import vuetify from './plugins/vuetify';

new Vue({
  router,
  store,
  vuetify,
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')
```

However, when I try some examples from the documentation they look different in my browser (Google Chrome).

For example:

This is what my code produces:

```
<v-row align="center">
   <v-checkbox
      v-model="enabled"
      hide-details
      class="shrink mr-2 mt-0" 
   ></v-checkbox>
   <v-text-field
      :disabled="!enabled"
      label="I only work if you check the box"
   ></v-text-field>
</v-row>
```

[image]

And this is the same control on documentation website.

[image]

The same goes with icons. With this code:

```
<v-text-field
    label="Prepend inner"
    prepend-inner-icon="mdi-map-marker"
></v-text-field>
```

[image]

But the documentation example looks like this. (Note that I have smaller spaces between icon/control and label text)
[image]

Why this might be happening and how to fix this?

Versions:

```
vue@2.6.11
vuetify@2.3.13
```

Comment: the checkbox example looks like the `mr-2` isn't taking affect, do you have any other styling that may be overwriting the margin styling? Are you sure you included the class with correct spelling?

Comment: Yeap, that was exactly the case. `mr-2` wasn't taking effect because it was outside of `v-app` tag. Thank you